# current_user defined in application.rb will not work in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

This is from my application_controller.rb

```
 private

  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

And this is a create method from my comments_controller.rb

```
def create

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
    @user.comments.create(:user_id => @user.id, :commenter => current_user.login, :body => params[:comment][:body])
    respond_to do |format| 
         format.js 
         format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') } 
     end
  end
```

When called it says:

undefined method `login' for nil:NilClass

What could be stopping current_user from being found?

Comment: try after moving it above private, private methods are only callable inside same class.

Comment: Moving above private doesn't help

Comment: @RahulSingh private methods can be called inside child classes, too. That's a difference in Ruby between other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is found correctly. If not, there would be a `NoMethodError`.

In your case `current_user` is simply returning `nil`. Then you try to use `.login` on `nil` which leads to the error you see:

```
undefined method `login' for nil:NilClass
```

So try to find out why `current_user` returns `nil` in your create action. Maybe because it can happen that the `session[:user_id]` is not set or no user is found?

---

Based on the comments the problem is the CSRF protection. Because of the CSRF error, the session is not initialized in `create` and therefore `current_user` is blank.

CSRF protection is usually enabled in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

You should find out why CSRF protection kicks in and fix it. Disabling it makes your site insecure. Take a look at the [ruby security guide about CSRF](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

Comment: How can session[:user_id] not be set? It is the logged in user that is making the comment

Comment: Try outputting it in `create` at the beginning with `puts current_user.inspect` to see that it is really `nil`, same with `session[:user_id]`. If it is not `nil`, are you sure the error comes from the line in your `create` action and not from some other line?

Comment: p current_user produces no output when placed in create. I am getting Can't verify CSRF token authenticity  Could that be anything to do with it?

Comment: Yeah, looks like your session is not initialized correctly on `POST` and therefore `session[:user_id]` is empty --> no user

Comment: 'Yeah, looks like your session is not initialized correctly on POST' Any ideas how to fix it? Yet I can send emails from the site?

Comment: There is no way to tell without more info about how you build/send your form. I can only assume you have `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in your `ApplicationController`, so on a CSRF error there is no error raised but the session is not initialized. And I think you are sending the `POST` by ajax, maybe without having added [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to your `application.js` assets? Wild guesses though.

Comment: Sorted. You gave me the clue protect_from_forgery  in application_controller.rb Commented it out and all is fine. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the CSRF part. So please upvote and accept it as we found your problem.

Comment: Did this solve your question? If so, accept the answer.